# json-twitter list of array - retrieve actual tweet

Tags: php, json, twitter

```
Array
(
    [statuses] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [metadata] => Array
                        (
                            [result_type] => recent
                            [iso_language_code] => en
                        )

                    [created_at] => Wed Jul 30 17:15:35 +0000 2013
                    [id] => 3626225823751905
                    [id_str] => 3626225875190528
                    [text] =>Where are you?
```

---

```
                     [user] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 192994
                            [id_str] => 192994
                            [name] => Stupido
                            [screen_name] => Stupido
                            [location] => 
                            [description] =>I'm who I'm
                            [url] => http://t.co/xehevCed
                            [entities] => Array
                                (
                                    [url] => Array
                                        (
                                            [urls] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [url] => http://t.co/xehevCed
```

---

SO, I have my 20 recent tweets - JSON_decode() : 
But, How can I actually retrieve the text and the URL? Its nested arrays.

Can some one help ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Abraham Twitteroauth?

Try this:

```
$parameters = array('screen_name' => 'twitter' /* your screen name */, 'result_type' => 'recent', 'count' => '20' /* your limit */  );

$content = $connection->get("statuses/user_timeline", $parameters);

for($i = 0; $i < 20 /* your limit */; ++$i) {

echo $content[$i]->text . $content[$i]->user->url . "<hr />";

}
```